# Scrapy callback function, how to parse several pages?

Tags: python, scrapy

I want to make a crawler that starts at a url (page1), and follows a link to a new page, page2. On page2 it should follow a link to page3. Then I want to scrape some data on page3.

However, I'm a noob at scraping and can't get the callback function to work. Here's my code:

```
class allabolagnewspider(CrawlSpider):
name="allabolagnewspider"
# allowed_domains = ["byralistan.se"]
start_urls = [
    "http://www.allabolag.se/5565794400/befattningar"
]

rules = (
    Rule(LinkExtractor(allow = "http://www.allabolag.se",
                       restrict_xpaths=('//*[@id="printContent"]//a[1]'),
                       canonicalize=False),
         callback='parse_link1'),
)

def parse_link1(self, response):
    hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
    return Request(hxs.xpath('//*[@id="printContent"]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[4]/td/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/a').extract(), callback=self.parse_link2)

def parse_link2(self, response):
    for sel in response.xpath('//*[@id="printContent"]'):
        item = AllabolagnewItem()
        item['Byra'] = sel.xpath('/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[3]/td/h1').extract()
        item['Namn'] = sel.xpath('/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[3]/td/h1').extract()
        item['Gender'] = sel.xpath('/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[3]/td/h1').extract()
        item['Alder'] = sel.xpath('/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[3]/td/h1').extract()
        yield item
```

However, when I run it I get the following error message: 
"TypeError: Request url must be str or unicode, got list:"

If I got it correctly I mess up when I try to return my request for parse_link1. What should I do?

Edit:

Here's the working code (still got a few issues though but the specific problem was solved):

```
class allabolagnewspider(CrawlSpider):
name="allabolagnewspider"
# allowed_domains = ["byralistan.se"]
start_urls = [
    "http://www.allabolag.se/5565794400/befattningar"
]

rules = (
    Rule(LinkExtractor(allow = "http://www.allabolag.se",
                       restrict_xpaths=('//*[@id="printContent"]//a[2]'),
                       canonicalize=False),
         callback='parse_link1'),
)

def parse_link1(self, response):
    for href in response.xpath('''//*[@id="printContent"]/div[2]/table//tr[4]/td/table//tr/td[2]/a/@href''').extract():
        print "hey"
        yield Request(response.urljoin(href), callback=self.parse_link2)

def parse_link2(self, response):
    for sel in response.xpath('//*[@id="printContent"]'):
        print "hey2"
        item = AllabolagnewItem()
        item['Byra'] = sel.xpath('./div[2]/table//tr[3]/td/h1/text()').extract()
        item['Namn'] = sel.xpath('./div[2]/table//tr[3]/td/h1/text()').extract()
        item['Gender'] = sel.xpath('./div[2]/table//tr[7]/td/table[1]//tr[1]/td/text()').extract()
        item['Alder'] = sel.xpath('./div[2]/table//tr[3]/td/h1/text()').extract()
        yield item
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `parse_link1`, you're passing a list, the result of `.extract()` on a `SelectorList` (result of calling `.xpath()` on the `hxs` selector), as value for `url`, the first argument of `Request` constructor, while a single value is expected.

Use `.extract_first()` instead:

```
return Request(hxs.xpath('//*[@id="printContent"]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[4]/td/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/a').extract_first()
```

---

Edit after OP's comment on

```
"TypeError: Request url must be str or unicode, got NoneType:"
```

This is due to a "too-conservative" XPath expression, probably given by your browser Inspect tools I guess (I tested your XPath in Chrome and it works for [this example page](http://www.allabolag.se/befattningshavare/de_Sauvage-Nolting%252C_Henri_Jacob_Jan/f6da68933af6383498691f19de7ebd4b))

The trouble is with `.../table/tbody/tr/...`. The thing is `<tbody>` is rarely there for real HTML pages written by people or even templates (written by people).
HTML wants a `<table>` to have a `<tbody>` but nobody really cares, and browsers cope fine (and they inject the missing `<tbody>` element to host the `<tr>` rows.)

So, although it's not strictly equivalent XPath, it's usually fine to:

- either omit `tbody/` and use the `table/tr` pattern
- or use `table//tr`

See it in action with `scrapy shell`:

```
$ scrapy shell http://www.allabolag.se/befattningshavare/de_Sauvage-Nolting%252C_Henri_Jacob_Jan/f6da68933af6383498691f19de7ebd4b
>>>
>>> # with XPath from browser tool (I assume), you get nothing for the "real" downloaded HTML 
>>> response.xpath('//*[@id="printContent"]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[4]/td/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/a')
[]
>>>
>>> # or, omitting `tbody/`
>>> response.xpath('//*[@id="printContent"]/div[2]/table/tr[4]/td/table/tr/td[2]/a')
[<Selector xpath='//*[@id="printContent"]/div[2]/table/tr[4]/td/table/tr/td[2]/a' data=u'<a href="/befattningshavare/de_Sauvage-N'>]

>>> # replacing "/table/tbody/" with "/table//" (tbody is added by browser to have "correct DOM tree")
>>> response.xpath('//*[@id="printContent"]/div[2]/table//tr[4]/td/table//tr/td[2]/a')
[<Selector xpath='//*[@id="printContent"]/div[2]/table//tr[4]/td/table//tr/td[2]/a' data=u'<a href="/befattningshavare/de_Sauvage-N'>]
>>>
>>> # suggestion: use the <img> tag after the <a> as predicate
>>> response.xpath('//*[@id="printContent"]/div[2]/table//tr/td/table//tr/td/a[img/@alt="personprofil"]')
[<Selector xpath='//*[@id="printContent"]/div[2]/table//tr/td/table//tr/td/a[img/@alt="personprofil"]' data=u'<a href="/befattningshavare/de_Sauvage-N'>]
>>>
```

Also, you need:

- to get the "href" attribute value (adding `@href` at the end of your XPath)
- build an absolute URL. `response.urljoin()` is a handy shortcut for this

Continuing in scrapy shell:

```
>>> response.xpath('//*[@id="printContent"]/div[2]/table/tr[4]/td/table/tr/td[2]/a/@href').extract_first()
u'/befattningshavare/de_Sauvage-Nolting%252C_Henri_Jacob_Jan_Personprofil/f6da68933af6383498691f19de7ebd4b'
>>> response.urljoin(u'/befattningshavare/de_Sauvage-Nolting%252C_Henri_Jacob_Jan_Personprofil/f6da68933af6383498691f19de7ebd4b')
u'http://www.allabolag.se/befattningshavare/de_Sauvage-Nolting%252C_Henri_Jacob_Jan_Personprofil/f6da68933af6383498691f19de7ebd4b'
>>>
```

In the end, your callback could become:

```
def parse_link1(self, response):
    # .extract() returns a list here, after .xpath()
    # so you can loop, even if you have 1 result
    #
    # XPaths can be multiline, it's easier to read for long expressions
    for href in response.xpath('''
        //*[@id="printContent"]
           /div[2]
            /table//tr[4]/td
             /table//tr/td[2]/a/@href''').extract():
        yield Request(response.urljoin(href),
                      callback=self.parse_link2)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. However, now I get a new error:
"TypeError: Request url must be str or unicode, got NoneType:"

Comment: Thanks a million for your updated answer! Now it crawls the linked pages perfectly. 

However, I still got problem with the callback function "callback=self.parse_link2". It doesn't scrape the page. When I run the code it only crawls but does not scrape the site. I even got identical output when I deleted the whole parse_link2 function. Am I doing the callback function correctly?

Comment: @brrrglund, inside a loop over results of a selector `.xpath()` call, you need to use **relative XPaths** (starting with `./` to be safe) instead of absolute XPaths (starting with `/`) -- the latter ones start from the root of the document. Try `sel.xpath('./div[2]/table//tr[3]/td/h1').extract()` (I removed `tbody/` too)

Comment: I tried this too but it still does not work. I even tried "sel.xpath('//h1').extract()" but it still doesn't scrape any data. Could the problem be elsewhere?

Comment: Use relative XPath, such as `.//h1` (notice the leading dot), not `//h1`

Comment: scrapy shell example: https://gist.github.com/redapple/716132c832d60c4d07fe
so the callback should work. If you don't get into the callback, that's another problem. Worth another question on StackOverflow

Comment: Really appreciate your patience with me @paul-trmbrth. I tried inserting the following code in parse_link1, but it does not print "hey". A similar crawler I did prints it perfectly when I insert it in the corresponding loop:

    `def parse_link1(self, response):
        for href in response.xpath('''//*[@id="printContent"]/div[2]/table//tr[4]/td/table//tr/td[2]/a/@href''').extract():
            print "hey"
            yield scrapy.Request(response.urljoin(href), callback=self.parse_link2)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105263/discussion-between-paul-trmbrth-and-brrrglund).

Answer (score 0):

`hxs.xpath(...).extract()` is returning a list and not a string.
Try to iterate over the list yielding requests or select the correct url you want from the list.

After that, it will work only if links in the page are absolute paths. If they are relative, you need to build the absolute path.